# What is the function of the "#" in this string?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am quite new to VBA and I would like to understand what the function is of the `#` in this string:

```
"#" & Format(dteLOOP, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#,"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `#` is the delimiter for date/time literals in Access-SQL, or, as HansUp pointed out in the comments, in VBA code.

Comment: So the entire thing must be about [composing a query via concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683).

Comment: `#` is also used to delimit Date/Time literal values in VBA code, e.g. `Dim MyDate As Date : MyDate = #2019-12-25#`

Answer (score 1):

Here `&` operator is concatenating strings. There is no significance for "#".
The expected output will have a "#" before and after.

for example:

the date will be : **#10/11/2019#,**